# Facebook - get user name through API

Tags: django, facebook-graph-api

If I do

```
https://graph.facebook.com/user-id
```

the complete JSON response is:

```
{
  "id": "525190867", 
  "name": "Syed Saqlain", 
  "first_name": "Syed", 
  "last_name": "Saqlain", 
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/syed.saqlain.77", 
  "username": "syed.saqlain.77", 
  "birthday": "08/14/1985", 
  "locale": "en_US", 
  "updated_time": "2012-06-04T23:23:57+0000"
}
```

If I only want to get the name on a jinja template, is there a way to get the full name only without parsing the JSON packet?

For example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/user-id/name/
```

I am using python-django, BTW.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the results by requesting

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID?fields=name
```

But you'll still get a [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) object back that you'll need to parse.